# husky spawns successfully but spawn_model node not found

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic, roslauch, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running the `husky_empty_world.launch` file (see below) inside the `husky_gazebo` package. Inside this launch file is call to `spawn_husky.launch` file (see below).

I have this piece of code inside the `spawn_husky.launch` file -

```
   <node name="spawn_husky_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
            args="-x $(arg x)
                  -y $(arg y)
                  -z $(arg z)
                  -Y $(arg yaw)
                  -unpause
                  -urdf
                  -param robot_description
                  -model $(arg robot_namespace)" />
```

But when I launch the `husky_empty_world.launch` file and run `rosnode list` in the terminal, I only see the following items -

```
/base_controller_spawner
/ekf_localization
/gazebo
/gazebo_gui
/joy_teleop/joy_node
/joy_teleop/teleop_twist_joy
/robot_state_publisher
/rosout
/twist_marker_server
/twist_mux
```

There's no `node` named `spawn_model` in this list even though a Husky bot is getting spawned in the Gazebo world. Why is this happening?

**husky_empty_world.launch**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>

  <arg name="world_name" default="worlds/empty.world"/>

  <arg name="laser_enabled" default="true"/>
  <arg name="realsense_enabled" default="false"/>

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(arg world_name)"/> <!-- world_name is wrt GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH environment variable -->
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>

  <include file="$(find husky_gazebo)/launch/spawn_husky.launch">
    <arg name="laser_enabled" value="$(arg laser_enabled)"/>
    <arg name="realsense_enabled" value="$(arg realsense_enabled)"/>
  </include>

</launch>
```

**spawn_husky.launch**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>

  <arg name="multimaster" default="false"/>

  <arg name="robot_namespace" default="/"/>

  <arg name="x" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="y" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="z" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="yaw" default="0.0"/>

  <arg name="laser_enabled" default="$(optenv HUSKY_LMS1XX_ENABLED false)"/>
  <arg name="realsense_enabled" default="$(optenv HUSKY_REALSENSE_ENABLED false)"/>
  <arg name="urdf_extras" default="$(optenv HUSKY_URDF_EXTRAS)"/>

  <!-- Optionally disable teleop control -->
  <arg name="joystick" default="true" />

  <group ns="$(arg robot_namespace)">

    <group if="$(arg multimaster)">
      <include file="$(find husky_description)/launch/description.launch" >
        <arg name="robot_namespace" value="$(arg robot_namespace)"/>
        <arg name="laser_enabled" default="$(arg laser_enabled)"/>
        <arg name="realsense_enabled" default="$(arg realsense_enabled)"/>
        <arg name="urdf_extras" default="$(arg urdf_extras)"/>
      </include>

      <include file="$(find multimaster_launch)/launch/multimaster_gazebo_robot.launch">
        <arg name="gazebo_interface" value="$(find husky_control)/config/gazebo_interface.yaml" />
        <arg name="robot_namespace" value="$(arg robot_namespace)"/>
      </include>

      <!-- For multimaster bringuplaunch, need to load the controller config -->
      <rosparam command="load" file="$(find husky_control)/config/control.yaml" />
    </group>

    <!-- For single master bringup, run robot control on the gazebo master -->
    <!-- Note that husky_description/description.launch is already included in husky_control/control.launch. -->
    <group unless="$(arg multimaster)">
      <include file="$(find husky_control)/launch/control.launch">
        <arg name="multimaster" value="$(arg multimaster)"/>
        <arg name="laser_enabled" value="$(arg laser_enabled)"/>
        <arg name="realsense_enabled" default="$(arg realsense_enabled)"/>
        <arg name="urdf_extras" value="$(arg urdf_extras)"/>
      </include>
      <include file="$(find husky_control)/launch/teleop.launch">
        <arg name="joystick" value="$(arg joystick)" />
      </include>
    </group>

    <!-- Additional nodes for specific accessories -->
    <group if="$(arg realsense_enabled)">
      <include file="$(find husky_gazebo)/launch/realsense.launch" />
    </group>

    <!-- Spawn robot in gazebo -->
    <node name="spawn_husky_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
        args="-x $(arg x)
              -y $(arg y)
              -z $(arg z)
              -Y $(arg yaw)
              -unpause
              -urdf
              -param robot_description
              -model $(arg robot_namespace)" />

  </group>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370501/husky-spawns-successfully-but-spawn_model-node-not-found/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2021-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

You are not seeing `/spawn_model` under `rosnode list` because it is not a normal node, it's actually a small python script that makes a service call to the `/gazebo` node, so it disappears when it completes its job.

If you need a more in-depth explanation, I made this video that could help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfVODpwVbS4&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=TheConstruct

---

Originally posted by [rodrigo55](https://answers.ros.org/users/53015/rodrigo55/) with karma: 156 on 2021-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-03**:
Thanks!

P.S. - It was very exciting to (sort of) feature on [The Construct](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCt6Lag-vv25fTX3e11mVY1Q) channel :-P
I have been following the channel for quite some time now. Thank you for what you guys do :-)

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2021-03-11**:
Can you please update your answer with main points from the video? If your video goes down or isn't available for certain regions then your answer/solution isn't as useful. Also, some prefer text to 14+ minute video